# Inline hover color

Tags: html, css

Can we set hover color inline to li tag ?
    Actually I have a li attribute where I wanted to put the color dynamically coming from database. I have tried some way, below is one of them,

```
       <li style = {'color:blue !important'}:hover{'color:pink !important'}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: not getting what you want to say.

Comment: Using inline pseudo style is not possible. You can try using <style>Your css here</style> on the page where your element exist.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)